# Where can I find auditory records of Chinese Mandarin within 1930-1970?

Tags: phonology, chinese, resource-request, mandarin

I am doing research on pure Chinese and I need a auditory recording made between 1930-1970. I searched for subject of anthropology in Hong Kong local library and found nothing material in auditory type. Are there any other ways?

Comment: There were quite a few Mandarin movies made in that period. Are they unsuitable for your task?

Comment: Usually, the VLO ( https://vlo.clarin.eu/ ) is a good place to start a search, but I found nothing for the time period you request (which is difficult to access, because all recordings of that time are copyrighted and usually not distributable). So you need to build a corpus on your own. Besides films, there are also radio and TV records that you can try to acquire.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!  Now we need to expand the sample period from 1950 to 1990.